# Is compile time polymorphism runtime polymorphism like this?

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism

From research this what I've learned:

overloading, operator overloading and overriding is what we called polymorphism.

Polymorphism means same entity behaving differently at times

For example:

Parametric

```
add(12, 13);
add(12.2, 13.3);
```

same entity( *add()* ) behaving different at times( *works for double, works for int* ).

//templates work here also

Ad-hoc

```
Animal dogInstance = new Dog();
Animal catInstance = new Cat();
dogInstance.sound(); //bark
catInstance.sound(); //meow
```

same entity( *sound()* ) behaving different at times
sound() will work according to what instance(dog or cat) ).

overloading, template and generics happens at compile time(compile time polymorphism).
overriding, operator overloading happens at runtime(runtime polymorphism).

Parametric polymorphism is when the same code can be applied to multiple data types.
ex. overloading, template and generics

Ad-hoc polymorphism is when different code is used for different data-types.
ex. overriding, operator overloading

Additional question:

> Why is operator overloading ad-hoc (dynamic binding)?

Also:

If you are a programmer should you mind these things like runtime polymorphism, compile time polymorphism, dynamic linking, static linking, framework meaning,
difference between framework and library, what is heavyweigth frameworks means what is lightweight framework means etc, or should I just continue programming, as long as my program works?

Comment: Please edit your post to use `Sentence-Case`.. We will manage..

Comment: So, your question is if you should deep understand what you are doing or if you can just "don't care" as long as your program works, do I get this right?

Comment: Most of us here can read very well without you having to **USE ALL CAPS AND BOLD!!**

Comment: sorry i thought it would help

Answer (score 2):

I will try answering your two questions little differently.

**Compile Time/Run Time**: At compile time, compiler can only validate what is syntactically correct. It is the run time, when it can perform behavioral evaluation. e.g.

> If you have two classes `B` and `C` extending `A`. There is one method is 
>         declared  to return `A`. In your caller, you expect that it is going to return
>         instance of `B`. You may type cast return value to `B` as `(B)A`. Compiler 
>         will not complain any issue here. But if at run time, it finds, your method
>         is return instance of `c`, it will fail.

All I am trying to explain here is: there are some behaviors which can only be evaluated at runtime.

**Programming**: When you are writing small tutorial programs, all you care is the success of the program and your basic learning. When you write bigger/heavy usage applications, you have to be very careful. Everything e.g. String concatenation, variable selection, number of iterations, object references matters a lot.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you doesn't have operator overloading, even for `==` which confuses newbie Java programmers.

You need to understand basic polymorphism principles but I would make sure you know all the high level features of your programming before lifting the cover.

I don't think there is a standard definition of what is a heavy weight or light weight framework.  I imagine its mostly a design strategy to either to include everything in one library or to be as simple as possible.

Comment: sorry i forgot there is no operator overloading in java. For you what is ad hoc polymorphism and parametric polymorphism

Comment: They are not terms I have come across in Java.

Comment: Its worth nothing that in Java the JIT can optimize polymorphism based on runtime behaviour. This means it can applied statically in apparently dynamic situations e.g. Using an interface can still be inlined if only two different classes are used.